# Использование ES6 модулей с Webpack

Tags: npm, ecmascript-6, webpack, модули

Мне нужно использовать ES6 модули для приложения на React+Flux.
Как я понял - для того чтобы их использовать нужен Webpack, я вроде как настроил его, и даже что-то работает.

например:

**welcome.js**

```
"use strict";
export default function (message) {
    console.log("Welcome ${message}");
};
```

и 
**home.js**

```
"use strict";
import welcome from './welcome';
welcome("home");
```

адекватно взаимодействуют, и выводят то что нужно.

но как только я пытаюсь подключить любой модуль, загруженный через npm:

**home.js**

```
import request from 'request';
```

у меня при попытке сборки начинается ад в командной строке типа такого:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите плз, как правильно использовать ES6 модули а то меня уже плавит.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "gitter-demo-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^6.9.2",
    "express": "~3.4.4",
    "jade": "~0.35.0",
    "passport": "~0.2.0",
    "passport-oauth2": "~1.1.1",
    "request": "~2.27.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.9.0",
    "mocha": "",
    "nodemon": "~1.0.15",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "pretest": "make restart-test-server",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test mocha",
    "posttest": "make stop-test-server"
  }
}
```

и **webpack.config.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry : "./home",            
    output : {
        filename : "build.js"    
    },

    watch : true ,               

    watchOptions : {
        aggregateTimeout : 100   
    },

    devtool : "source-map",      

    module : {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,             
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
              presets: ['es2015'],
              plugins: ['transform-runtime']
            }
        }]
    },
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Необходимо добавить в *webpack.config.js* параметр `target` со значением `"node"`:

```
{
    target: 'node'
}
```

Эта опция говорит *Webpack*'у о том, под какую среду собирается бандл. По умолчанию значение этой опции установлено в `"web"` и бандл собирается под браузеры. В отличие от среды *Node.js*, у браузеров нет таких "встроенных" модулей как *fs*, *tls*, *net* и т.д. (с ними у вас вылетают ошибки), следовательно при сборке для браузера Webpack старается их найти в папке *node_modules/*, где их очевидно нет, что и является результатом ошибки. При переключении среды на *Node.js*, *Webpack* будет автоматически игнорировать подключения встроенных *Node.js* модулей и сборка пройдет успешно.

[Пункт в документации Webpack о параметре target](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#target)